# Meteor: Iron route not to the right route

Tags: meteor, routes, iron

So I've a navbar, and I've made my way to a sub dir in "Games" called "Cross" so, /games/cross. Now from that page, I'm trying to acess the Games page again from navbar but its showing /games/games... How do I fix this? I have the following...

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layoutDefault'
});

Router.route('/', function(){
    this.render('main');
});

Router.route('/contact', {
    template: 'contact'
});

Router.route('/games', {
    template: 'games'
});

Router.route('/games/cross', {
    action: function() {
        if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['normal' , 'admins'])) {
            this.render('cross')
        }
        else
            this.render('denied')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, once you are in `/games/cross` page, you use your navbar to try to navigate back to the `/games` page, but your browser location bar now displays `/games/games` instead of just `/games`, and probably your router does not do anything? (or goes to whatever you have configured for route not found)

It might rather be an issue in the links of your navbar: have you tried prepending a slash `/` at the beginning of your `href` attribute value, so that the link is relative to your domain, not to the current page?

```html
<a href="/games">Games</a>
```

Instead of:

```html
<a href="games">Games</a>
```

Comment: You sir, are right. Can't believe I missed that. TBH I didnt even think it would be an issue :/

Answer (score 4):

Also you could use a helper function `pathFor`, Which returns the URL path component of any route.

### syntax

```
{{pathFor 'path name'}}
```

To use `pathFor` you have to add a `name` property to your route.

```
Router.route('/contact', {
    name: 'content-view'
    template: 'contact'
});

<a href="{{pathFor 'content-view'}}">contact</a>
```

So if you ever decide to change the your route, you don't have to update all your links manually.